# Selenium Xpath 'Starts-with' function syntax error chrome path

Tags: xpath

I am trying to use the start-with function to validate an Xpath but it displayed syntax error in chrome path please suggest me proper syntax if below syntax is wrong

HTML tag be like

```
<tr class="single" name="RevenueLine_bd82340357-4409lkasdf" xpath="1" >
```

try to find xpath like

```
//tr[starts-with(@name,'RevenueLine')]
```

thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't see any issue with the xpath, provide the html tag matches with the updated question on top. Can you please make sure the html tag is correct and share the screenshot of the error that you are getting.

Comment: It's much easier to diagnose a syntax error if you can see the error message. Please don't ask us to work blindfolded!

Comment: You forget the "s" in "starts-with" in your message. Don't forget it when you write your XPath expression in Chrome. Otherwise, another option : `//tr[starts-with(normalize-space(@name),"RevenueLine")]`